# How to create custom SOAP api for magento 2.0?

Tags: api, soap-api-v2, magento-2.0, web-services

How to create custom SOAP api in magento 2.0? Please share you link if you have already work on it.

Answer (score 1):

To create custom SOAP api for Magento 2.0

1. Create [service contracts](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-contracts.html). These are set of data and service interfaces.  Sample module for service contracts can be found on [Magento github](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-servicecontract-new).
2. [Expose services as web api services](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-to-web-service.html).

Comment: Hi, @Arkadii , nice article and I will check it but can't understand how can I manage with custom, can you please elaborate.

Comment: Have you already created service contracts? Could you give me an interface, which you want to expose

Comment: Hi, I can't understand exactly how to create service contracts, can you please provide other documentation for better understanding.

Comment: Try to explore this one: https://www.ashsmith.io/magento2/module-from-scratch-module-part-2-models/

Comment: Thanx, i will check it and let u know.

Comment: @Arkadii, is it necessary that we have to create all the methods like save(), delete() for Service Contracts for creating custom SOAP api